# Can not margin surface in Android 2.2?

Tags: android, margin, surfaceview

Please help, I can not configure out why setting layout in these code work on Android 4.0 but not on Android 2.2:

```
SurfacePreview mPreview = new SurfacePreview (mActivity, null);

LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(200, 200);

((ActivityPreview)mActivity).addContentView(mPreview,  lp);

ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mPreview
.getLayoutParams();

mlp.setMargins(100, 100, 0, 0);
```

Comment: What error do you get? If you don't get an error, could you define "not working in 2.2"?

Answer (score 0):

```
mlp.topMargin=100;
mlp.leftMargin=100;
```

try set the value directly, instead of using setMargins function;